# How to see processed jobs in Resque?

Tags: ruby, resque

`Resque` has a great web interface on which we can see the pending and failed jobs.

But where are the 'proccessed jobs'? How can I know what I have done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a nice plugin called [resque-status](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status) that might be of use to you.